# How to Convert a Integral into a SymPy Previewable img (Python)

Tags: python, sympy

So i already have the answer to the problem thanks to simpy.integrate(x,a,b) (where x is the function that i write on a entry) but i want to also show the user input like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeko4.jpg)
, because well, evaluate() can be a bit tricky, and a visual feedback would be great.
I am using Sympify but i really dont know how to make it to read the input as a integral

```html
integral=sp.sympify(integral(Funcion.get(),(x,inf.get(),sup.get())))
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the connection with your code and with the image (link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the example taken from the image (external link). Use `Integral` class to store an non-evaluated integral and `doit()` to perform the operation. Each of these results will be part of a side of an equation. Use the [`preview`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html?highlight=render#preview) to view the "formula" in different forms, LaTeX, png dvi, ps, or pdf.

```
from sympy import *
x, k = symbols('x k')

# test integrand
expr = x**3 + 7*x**2 + 3*k*x
domain = (x, 0, 15)

# LHS and RHS of the formula
I_expr = Integral(expr, domain)
I_res = I_expr.doit().factor()

# formula
final_expr = Eq(I_expr, I_res)

# check doc for further possibilities
preview(final_expr, output='png', viewer='gimp')
```

Comment: tanks, is working right now https://imgur.com/vrKOwiJ